# Topics to master before taking Calculus AB?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking Precalculus this summer and I will be taking Calculus AB (I) this fall. I'm strong in certain points in Algebra, I'm currently working on polishing my skills before I take my final ACT & SAT in the coming months. Any tips regarding how to go in to class prepared and not end up failing like many of my seniors would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Trigonometry, specifically the unit circle. Geometric and algebraic intuition about a line. Summation notation. Geometric notions of area and volume. Basically all of what you covered in Pre-Calculus

Comment: Really? It's weird cause I get a massive chunk of people saying hardly anything is used in calc, and then a small handful say a lot of it is related

Comment: What Jonathan said except for the last sentence.  I'd say almost none of what's covered in precalculus is really necessary.  For example, solving logarithmic equations, solving polynomial/rational inequalities, solving exponential equations, anything to do with complex numbers...  that's all unnecessary.  But definitely do have a firm grasp on simplifying exponential expressions (may be more of a calc 2/BC thing) and factoring polynomials.

Comment: You need a strong working knowledge of elementary algebra. $(a+b)^2 \neq a^2 + b^2$, $\log(xy) = \log(x) + \log(y)$, etc.

Comment: If you have internalized high school algebra so that you can do it almost effortlessly, that will help a lot. For example, simplifying expressions like $\frac{(x+h)^2 - x^2}{h}$. Also, it is important to have a certain kind of number sense, for example: if $h$ is very small then how does the size of $h^2$ compare to the size of $h$? (Answer: It's much smaller, of course.) If you find gaps in your knowledge as you learn calculus, go back and fill the gaps right then, don't let them persist.

Answer (score 4):

I've taught a lot of first-year calculus, and here are the things that trip people up the most:

- Not knowing the unit circle and the definitions of the six trig functions.
- Not knowing how to interpret negative and fractional exponents.
- Not knowing how to cancel rational algebraic expressions, i.e., polynomial over polynomial.
- Thinking that you can do things like $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$, or $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=a+b$
- Not having basic graph sense with the elementary functions and their transformations.

As an example of the third point, I've seen people think they can reduce an expression like $\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$ by canceling an $x$ from the first terms on top and bottom, yielding $\frac{x+1}{1}$. Ideally, seeing that done should set your teeth on edge.

To say more about the fourth point, many students seem to think that powers (and roots) distribute over addition, the same way multiplication does. Thus, you'll see people "simplifying", for example, $\sqrt{x^2+16}$ as $x+4$, or "simplifying" $(x+h)^2$ as $x^2+h^2$. Expressions just like these arise early in a first calculus class, and these mistakes are regrettably common.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 4th point? Sorry for the late reply

Comment: I added some details. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This list may not be at all exhaustive, but this is what I believe, having had taken Calculus AB (but took the BC exam - 5 with a 5 AB subscore) in 2012 and tutored calculus students.

- Be comfortable with solving equations, be they polynomial, exponential, or trigonometric.
- Be comfortable with trigonometry and the unit circle. I wouldn't rely too much on the identities, save for $\sin^2 u + \cos^2 u = 1$.
- Know how to graph a function. Sometimes drawing pictures is the way to go for some problems, and you'll learn this.
- With respect to some of the high school algebra, be comfortable with logarithms.
- Know how to manipulate fractions - sometimes in clever ways.
- Especially with the AP exam, be very comfortable with word problems. That is, can you identify what the question is asking? Do you know what information you need?

Again, this list may not be exhaustive nor is it perhaps the best reference. Others have mentioned in the comments what things they feel one should know before taking on AP calculus.

Comment: I would definitely recommend being familiar with angle sum fomulas for sine and cosine $$\cos(\theta + \phi) = \cos \theta\cos\phi - \sin\theta\sin\phi\\\sin(\theta + \phi) = \sin\theta\cos\phi + \cos\theta\sin\phi$$ and the relations $\sin(-\theta) = - \sin\theta, \cos(-\theta) = \cos \theta$. These are very commonly used in calculus. The sum formulas are important in developing the properties of sine and cosine, and the odd/even function formulas are quite useful in simplifying integration problems.